# Using two lists in a loop to assign two arguments in one function

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a function with 2 arguments. I would like to display the output using varying inputs of the arguments that can be found in two lists using a loop. I have executed the code successfully with one list (ages) but not with (ages) and (game).

```
# the below code works for 1 list assignment to the a argument  

for a in ages:
    print(age_price_event(a, 2))

# when I try this to assign the other argument I get an error.

for a in ages b in game:
    print(age_price_event(a, b))
```

File "", line 1
    for a in ages b in game:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
# Here is the function that I wrote

# Function that has two elements 
# a is the age of person
# b is the game
def age_price_event(a, b):
    str(b)
    if b == 1:            # looks to see if it is for 1
        if a < 4:              # if so execute code below
            return (0)    
        elif a < 18:
            return (10)
        else:
            return(15)     #Stop here
    if b==2:                     # looks to see if it is for 2
        if a < 4:                     # if so execute code below
            return (5)
        elif a < 18:
            return (55)
        else:
            return(66)                  #Stop Here
    else:               # if not game is not toady
        return ("That Game is not Today")

# here are the list to be assign to the arguments 
ages = [11, 22, 14, 25]
game = [ 1, 1, 2, 3]

# the below code works for 1 list assignment to the a argument  

for a in ages:
    print(age_price_event(a, 2))

# when I try this to assign the other argument I get an error.

for a in ages b in game:
    print(age_price_event(a, b))
```

the below code works for 1 list assignment to the a argument

```
55
66
55
66
```

when I try this to assign the other argument I get an error.

```
File "<ipython-input-158-2d5fb2f7d37f>", line 1
    for a in ages b in game:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use two for loops: `for a in ages:` `for b in games:` `print(age_price_event(a,b))`

Comment: Take a look to the `zip` function.

Comment: Use `for a, b in zip(ages, games):`

Comment: What is this `for a in ages b in game:` supposed to do? You want two `for` loops or a `zip` depending on what you want to pass to the function.

Comment: In your function, why do you convert b to string and then check `if b == 1`?

Comment: Good point, I was originally using it as a string input but changed to numerical.

Comment: @MrFuppes, `b` still is *not* a string unless it is assigned back.

Comment: @Austin: right, makes even less sense to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1):

This is called *parallel iteration* and can be written as follows:

```
for a, b in zip(ages, games):
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3**

```
for a, b in zip(ages, game):
    print(age_price_event(a, b))
```

**Python 2**

```
import itertools

for a, b in itertools.izip(ages, game):
    print(age_price_event(a, b))
```

In python 2 `itertools.izip` returns iterator instead of list, you want to use in Python 2 `itertools.izip` if you have so many elements.